# How to verify smart contract used with github link

Tags: tokens, erc-20, smart-contract-wallets, verify

Hello this is simple question how to verify a erc20 smart contract of github openzeppelin link?
I have erc20 token build with github openzeppelin link I want to verify it on explorer how to do it?
Anather question is that how use and implement IERC20 for erc20 transfer?

Comment: Please consider two separate questions, one for verifying smart contract and another one for your question related to IERC20 as this is not clear (MORE DETAILS) 

Regarding Verification
This is easier said than done because it will truly depend on the tools you are using to compile and external libraries. You need to collect some information such as:

 - Solidity Version you are using (e.g 0.6.6) 
 - Source code of the contract (minified makes it easier)
 - Constructor arguments
 - Optimization (if any) and runs number [default is usually no optimization]

Comment: I used openzeppelin github link to create erc20 token now I want use same erc20 token for presale smart contract how to import token to make transfer function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to the ERC-20 IERC20 problem

You need to create an IERC20 interface, then in your presale contract have something like

> IERC20 public payabletoken;

In your constructor you may have something like

```
constructor(IERC20 _token){
  payabletoken = _token
}
```

where _token is your deployed token address.

And in your "invest" function you can use

> payabletoken.trasferFrom(msg.sender, address(this),amount)